# Json, Jackson: polymorphism of one field, based on the value of other field

Tags: json, generics, jackson, polymorphism, discriminated-union

Basically I'm trying to integrate with some other service that sends payloads with the following shape

```json
{
  "storeId":"123",
  "type": "...",
  "data": ...,
  "createdAt": "...."
}
```

That shape never changes except for the property `data`, whose structure depends on the property `type`.

How can that be achieved with Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `JsonNode` to convert from string to json nodes `JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(fromValue);`
2. Then get your node using `JsonNode dataNode = node.get("data")`, same for type.
3. Get the class from the type node using `Class yourBeanClass = Class.forName("package.+type from step 2");`
4. Tokenize your data node using `JsonParser parser = mapper.treeAsTokens(dataNode);`
5. Finally get your bean instance by doing `YourBean bean = mapper.readValue(parser, yourBeanClass);`

Comment: I did so. And this is a valid answer, yet... Isn't there an annotation based way of doing so?